# Spring cloud dataflow is not working with spark

Tags: spring-cloud

I am working with spring cloud for spark program. I am using spark 1.3.1 with hortonworks environment. The spark program is going into "Accepted" state and its not proceeding further. I have run the same spark program in the edge node. Its working fine there. Please find the complete program for the same

```
package org.springframework.cloud.task.sparkapp.yarn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import scala.Tuple2;

/**
 * {@link CommandLineRunner} implementation that will run a Spark App in YARN mode using
 * configuration properties provided.
 *
 * @author Thomas Risberg
 */
public class SparkAppYarnRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkAppYarnRunner.class);

    @Autowired
    private Configuration hadoopConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private SparkAppYarnTaskProperties config;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.jar", config.getSparkAssemblyJar());
        sparkConf.set("HADOOP_HOME","file:///usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client");
        sparkConf.set("HADOOP_CONF_DIR","file:///etc/hadoop/conf");
        sparkConf.set("SPARK_HOME","file:///usr/hdp/current/spark-client");

        //sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions","-Dhdp.version=2.6.0.2.2.9.2-1");
        //sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions", "-Dhdp.version=2.6.0.2.2.9.2-1");
        sparkConf.set("spark.application.properties.file", "hdfs://<NAMENODE>:8020/db/e2e/sparkstudy/sparkapp/spark-defaults.conf");
        List<String> submitArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (StringUtils.hasText(config.getAppName())) {
            submitArgs.add("--name");
            submitArgs.add(config.getAppName());
        }
        submitArgs.add("--jar");
        submitArgs.add(config.getAppJar());
        submitArgs.add("--class");
        submitArgs.add(config.getAppClass());
        if (StringUtils.hasText(config.getResourceFiles())) {
            submitArgs.add("--files");
            submitArgs.add(config.getResourceFiles());
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(config.getResourceArchives())) {
            submitArgs.add("--archives");
            submitArgs.add(config.getResourceArchives());
        }
        submitArgs.add("--executor-memory");
        submitArgs.add(config.getExecutorMemory());
        submitArgs.add("--num-executors");
        submitArgs.add("" + config.getNumExecutors());
        submitArgs.add("--queue");
        submitArgs.add("" + config.getQueue());
        /*for (String arg : config.getAppConfs()) {
            submitArgs.add("--conf");
            submitArgs.add(arg);
        }*/
        for (String arg : config.getAppArgs()) {
            submitArgs.add("--arg");
            submitArgs.add(arg);
        }
        logger.info("Submit App with args: " + Arrays.asList(submitArgs));

        ClientArguments clientArguments =
                new ClientArguments(submitArgs.toArray(new String[submitArgs.size()]), sparkConf);
        clientArguments.isClusterMode();
        Tuple2<String,String>[] sparkConfigs = sparkConf.getAll();
        List<String> sparkConfValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Tuple2<String,String> tuple : sparkConfigs) {
            sparkConfValues.add(tuple.toString());
        }
        logger.info("All spark configs: " + Arrays.asList(sparkConfValues));
        Client client = new Client(clientArguments, hadoopConfiguration, sparkConf);
        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
        //System.setProperty("HADOOP_CONF_DIR","file:///etc/hadoop/conf");
        //System.setProperty("HADOOP_HOME", "file:///usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client");
        //System.setProperty("JAVA_HOME","file:///usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45");

        try {
            client.run();
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("Spark Application failed: " + t.getMessage(), t);
            throw new RuntimeException("Spark Application failed", t);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Exported the spring_application_json

export SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"app-name": "my-yarn-Pi", "app-class": "org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi", "app-jar": "hdfs://:8020/db/e2e/sparkstudy/sparkapp/sparkapp-client-task-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar", "spark-assembly-jar": "hdfs://:8020/db/e2e/sparkstudy/sparkapp/spark-assembly-1.3.1.2.2.9.2-1-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.9.2-1.jar", "queue":"dart","app-args": ["10"], "spring": {"hadoop": {"fsUri": "hdfs://:8020", "resourceManagerHost": "", "resourceManagerPort": 8032, "jobHistoryAddress": ":10020"}}}'

Answer (score 0):

These things do not look correct, unless you intentionally redacted them:

```
{"hadoop": {"fsUri": "hdfs://:8020", "resourceManagerHost": "", "resourceManagerPort": 8032, "jobHistoryAddress": ":10020"}
```

Also, in HDP, I believe the default `resourceManagerPort` is 8050, rather than 8032.